# request.form.get exception handling using a function

Tags: python, flask

What I am trying to do:
I have the user submit a form with a variable "symbol". I want to check that if the "Symbol" is blank (i.e. no value was entered), I throw an error.

The below code works well:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    if not request.form.get("symbol"):
         return apology("No symbol entered", 403)

    quote = lookup(request.form.get("symbol"))
    if quote is None:
         return apology("No such symbol found")

    return render_template("quoted.html", name=quote['name'], price=quote['price'], symbol=quote['symbol'])
```

where apology(message, code) is a function that renders a webpage with the message. lookup(symbol) is a function that looks up the symbol's name, price and returns a dictionary. This code works perfectly.

I have to put this code in several places and so I want to build a function that I can use.

So I tried:

```
def checkSymbol(symbol):
if not symbol:
    return apology("No symbol entered", 403)

quote = lookup(symbol)
if quote is None:
    return apology("No such symbol found")
else:
    return quote
```

and in the main body:

```
if request.method == "POST":
        quote = checkSymbol(request.form.get("symbol"))
        return render_template("quoted.html", name=quote['name'], price=quote['price'], symbol=quote['symbol'])
```

now if the user enters a valid symbol the code works fine and we are able to <DO STUFF WITH ...> but if the user leaves the symbol field blank, the error is not caught. Instead I get an error saying tuple keys cannot be strings.

Comment: When you make the call `checkSymbol(request.form.get("symbol"))`, it *evaluates to* `SOME_ERROR_CODE`, but then you don't *do anything with* that result in the main body.

Comment: I clarified above- if the "not symbol" condition is met, I am rendering an error HTML file. without the checkSymbol function, the errorpage gets rendered; with with function the errorpage doesn't show up and the code continues with the main body, eventually throwing an unhandled error.

Comment: Yes, the problem is the same. When you `return render_template("errorpage.html")` from `checkSymbol`, Flask does the rendering and produces an object representing the error page... but a result is not sent to the user's browser *because the main body does not return this object*.

Comment: Hm, i am sorry as I am very new to this so might  not be asking correctly. I updated the question above to show exactly what code I have and I think I am returning everything correctly? if it is wrong, can you please tell me which line and what needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know, what are you trying to do, but when you call `checkSymbol()` function, it just return value back, and main function will continue until to `return render_template...` so i think the better way to check that, is to make func which return "yes" or "no" and then in main function call  `apology(...)`

```
if request.method == "POST":
    if checkSymbol(request.form.get("symbol")) == "no":
         return apology("No symbol entered", 403)
    else:
         quote = lookup(request.form.get("symbol"))
         return render_template("quoted.html", name=quote['name'], price=quote['price'], symbol=quote['symbol'])
```

and `checkSymbol()` :

```
def checkSymbol(symbol):
   if not symbol:
       return "no"
   quote = lookup(symbol)
   if quote is None:
       return "no"
   else:
       return "yes"
```

Or something similar, I hope you understand what i trying to say.